# Design pattern strategy in MEF

Tags: .net, design-patterns, mef

I have method what returns objects implementing particular interface. Depends on argument method return different object. All implement the same interface so I can use the same method like Execute() on interface outside the method. 
This solution force me to avoid of using MEF. How can I use both solution at once? Importing constructor from MEF and isolation of different strategies in separate classes?

Here is an example code:

```
[Export(typeof(ICrowdMessageProcessorFactory))]
public class CrowdMessageProcessorFactory : ICrowdMessageProcessorFactory
{
    private readonly IDefaultCrowdRequestAnalyzer _defaultProcessor;

    [ImportingConstructor]
    public CrowdMessageProcessorFactory(IDefaultCrowdRequestAnalyzer defaultProcessor)
    {
        _defaultProcessor = defaultProcessor;
    }

    public Metadata PayloadMetadata { get; private set; }

    public ICrowdMessageProcessor Create(InsertCrowdsourcingEventRequest request, DateTime fireUtcDateTime)
    {
        if (request == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(request));
        }

        PayloadMetadata = Metadata.Create(request);
        var marketRegion = PayloadMetadata?.GetMarketRegion();

        switch (marketRegion)
        {
            case MarketRegion.Uk:
                return new UkCrowdMessageProcessor();
        }

        return new DefaultCrowdMessageProcessorAdapter(request, fireUtcDateTime, _defaultProcessor);
    }
}
```

And here is use of the method

```
    [ImportingConstructor]
    public CrowdResponseAnalyzer(
        ICrowdMessageProcessorFactory processorFactory)
    {
             _processorFactory = processorFactory;
    }

    public void Execute(InsertCrowdsourcingEventRequest request, DateTime fireUtcDateTime)
    {
        Guard.ArgumentNotNull(request, "request");

        try
        {
            ICrowdMessageProcessor processor = _processorFactory.Create(request, fireUtcDateTime);
            processor.Execute();
        }
        //(...)
    }
```

In summary:
I like to separate different strategies to different class, here in **UkCrowdMessageProcessor** and **DefaultCrowdMessageProcessorAdapter**. But in new this kind of class (**ICrowdMessageProcessor**) i need to use *ImportingConstructor* also. How can I do it?

Comment: How do you currently decide which object to return? Maybe share your code?

Comment: Please can you move your solution into an answer. This makes it clearer and helps others who may have the same problem. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution 1:
Use **CompositionContainer** and it method **GetExportedValue**. 
when it looks:

```
public ICrowdMessageProcessor Create(InsertCrowdsourcingEventRequest request, DateTime fireUtcDateTime)
    {
        if (request == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(request));
        }

        PayloadMetadata = Metadata.Create(request);

        var marketRegion = PayloadMetadata?.GetMarketRegion();
        switch (marketRegion)
        {
            case MarketRegion.Uk:
                return _cc.GetExportedValue<UkCrowdMessageProcessor>();
        }

        return PrepareDefaultCrowdMessageProcessor(request, fireUtcDateTime);
    }

    private ICrowdMessageProcessor PrepareDefaultCrowdMessageProcessor(InsertCrowdsourcingEventRequest request, DateTime fireUtcDateTime)
    {
        var processor = _cc.GetExportedValue<DefaultCrowdMessageProcessorAdapter>();
        processor.Initialize(request, fireUtcDateTime, _defaultProcessor);
        return processor;
    }
```

Solution 2: Use **ServiceLocator** and *GetInstance*

Solution 3: This one is the only one **right** from design point of view.

```
[Export(typeof(ICrowdMessageProcessorFactory))]
public class CrowdMessageProcessorFactory : ICrowdMessageProcessorFactory
{

    private readonly IDefaultCrowdRequestAnalyzer _defaultProcessor;

    private readonly UkCrowdMessageProcessor _ukCrowdMessageProcessor;

    private readonly DefaultCrowdMessageProcessorAdapter _defaultCrowdMessageProcessor;

    [ImportingConstructor]
    public CrowdMessageProcessorFactory(
        IDefaultCrowdRequestAnalyzer defaultProcessor, 
        UkCrowdMessageProcessor ukCrowdMessageProcessor,
        DefaultCrowdMessageProcessorAdapter defaultCrowdMessageProcessor)
    {
        _defaultProcessor = defaultProcessor;
        _ukCrowdMessageProcessor = ukCrowdMessageProcessor;
        _defaultCrowdMessageProcessor = defaultCrowdMessageProcessor;
    }

    public Metadata PayloadMetadata { get; private set; }

    public ICrowdMessageProcessor Create(InsertCrowdsourcingEventRequest request, DateTime fireUtcDateTime)
    {
        if (request == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(request));
        }

        PayloadMetadata = Metadata.Create(request);

        var marketRegion = PayloadMetadata?.GetMarketRegion();
        switch (marketRegion)
        {
            case MarketRegion.Uk:
                return _ukCrowdMessageProcessor;
        }

        return PrepareDefaultCrowdMessageProcessor(request, fireUtcDateTime);
    }

    private ICrowdMessageProcessor PrepareDefaultCrowdMessageProcessor(InsertCrowdsourcingEventRequest request, DateTime fireUtcDateTime)
    {
        _defaultCrowdMessageProcessor.Initialize(request, fireUtcDateTime, _defaultProcessor);
        return _defaultCrowdMessageProcessor;
    }
}
```